# blender crash on a specific project

Tags: objects, particles

please help I'm desperate to solve this issue because It keep bringing back to the start,
I have a project I'm working on and basically every time I start to implement the particle system when modify the values it crashes!! the weird thing afterwards its not opening that file at all for some reason !!

I have tried appending the objects from it and made new scene new file but again when I get to this point I get to the exact same issue

I tried all virsion of blender same issue!

I have beast machine so it cant be pc itself

I have **intel i9 9980xe processor on x299 designare ex
EVGA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti , 11GB GDDR5X
and 128 gb RAM**

please help

Comment: There's possibly something wrong with the file.  Can you share the blend? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help)) or failing that at least a screen shot of the console showing any messages?  One common reason is that the file was written with a more recent version of blender and you're trying to open it with an older version that doesn't understand it. Could that be the case?

Comment: thanks for your reply the file is larger than 30 (44 mg)https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1DZrkjmCuvrpaz_Rznr5xUPfk1hqqknRM?usp=sharing I have it uploaded to g drive

Comment: the file was created with the official 2.93 version I two older versions and the experiment 3.00 alpha but no luck !

Comment: It's not the PC, nor your drivers, but I don't think I can help you beyond that.  Blender is crashing with an access violation exception deep within the main draw routine.

Comment: did you try to open it with your device ?

Comment: Yes, and I get a crash report that tells me some more details, but I haven't found a combination of command line arguments that would allow me to salvage the file.  You might consider filing a bug report, but I don't know that the devs can do anything with it.